# Compare PCs to data with lsfit()

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with 2000 observations (rows) and 600 variables (columns). See reproducible example:

```
list <- list()

for(i in 1:600){
  list[[i]] <- sample(seq(0,0.6,l=2000))
}

df <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,list))
```

I want to perform PCA on the variables and then use lsfit to compare the fit between the principal components and the data (as well as some other data, but this is left out here). My first issue is that when I perform PCA on the data set as it is, my principle components have length 20000. I would expect them to have length 600. However, this is resolved by transposing the data frame.

```
pc_model <- prcomp(df, center=F, rank=3)
pcs <- pc_model$x # wrong length, why?


df_trans <- as.data.frame(t(df))
pc_model2 <- prcomp(df_trans, center=F, rank=3)
pcs2 <- pc_model2$x # correct length, why?
```

My next issue is that when I try to use lsfit() to compare my 2000 observations to the principal components, I get all sorts of complaints:

```
fit <- lsfit(df_trans, pcs2) # Error in lsfit(df_trans, pcs2) : only 600 cases, but 2001 variables
fit2 <- lsfit(df, pcs2) # Error in complete.cases(x, y, wt) : not all arguments have the same length
fit3 <- lsfit(df[1,], pcs2[,1]) # Error in complete.cases(x, y, wt) : not all arguments have the same length
```

With the transposed data frame, lsfit() complains that I have too many variables. With the non-transposed data frame, it argues that the arguments don´t have the same length, even when I only feed it one row from df (length=600) and one column from pcs2 (length=600). How do I get the least squared fits between my PCs and my 20000 observations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. first `pc_model$x` is just the coordinates of the observations in the new space defined by axises `(PC1, PC2, PC3)`, so you'll have as many rows as there are observations, i.e 2000 rows for 2000 observations.
2. `ls.fit(X, Y)` is trying to fit the model `Y = Xb + e` where Y and e are `(N,M)` matrices, X is `(N,K)` matrix and b is `(K,M)` vector. and K is the number of variables you want to use in the estimation (K=number of columns in the original X matrix + 1 if you want to calculate the coefficient of the intercept which is the default) also N>=K for this regression to be computable.

   - Running `fit2 <- lsfit(df, pcs)` will give correct output, as the conditions are verified, i.e same number of lines and N=2000>=K=601.
   - the error `Error in lsfit(df_trans, pcs2) : only 600 cases, but 2001 variables` is caused by df_trans having 2000 columns (variables + 1 for the intercept)  while pcs2 having only 600 rows. selecting the first 599 columns circumvents the error `lsfit(df_trans[,1:599] ,pcs2)`
   - the error `not all arguments have the same length` is caused by the arguments `complete.cases` call inside of ls.fit because df and pcs2 have different row numbers this error is thrown before reaching the conditional on different row numbers inside of lsfit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want the PCs derived from the transposed dataset (pc_model2$x) and I want to get the lsfit for those and all elements in df_trans/df. How is that possible when I need to have the same number of columns for all arguments in lsfit() and it is a criteria for all arguments that N>=K?

Comment: @Skårup the `N>=K` is a modelling constraint you can't have more dependent variables then you have observations it's like saying that a linear system has no solution when you have less equations then there are unknown parameters, I think you are interested in the residuals?

Comment: @Skårup if you are indeed interested in the residuals a solution would be to switch the order of the arguments that you pass to `lsfit` i.e `lsfit(pcs2, df_trans)` now you have less columns in your `X` then there are variables, then it's an easy calculation from there on.

Comment: I am interested in the coefficients between the PCs (length=600) and all the samples/observations (2000). Does that make sense?

Comment: @Skårup I didn't understand what you want, however you can achieve it by `y_i = x_i/b_i - e_i/bi` where b_i and e_i are the result of `lsfit`

Comment: Oh changing the order as you suggest also gives me the coefficients ```lsfit(pcs2, df_trans)```. This is just what I was looking for